# How will brain-computer interfacing work?

Tags: neural-network, brain-computer-interface

I have just been reading about Elon Musks new company **[Neuralink](https://neuralink.com/)**. He claims that it is possible to increase the communication speed between humans and computers by using direct brain interfaces which could help in exchanging large volumes of information in a short period of time. The speed with which humans generate written information is just a few bytes per second. But computers communicate with each other at a very fast rate.

**So my doubts are,**

1. ***Is such a thing even possible?*** I have this question because I believe that our brain does not understand binary.
2. It took me a few *whole minutes* for typing this question. It was not because of my inability to type fast. It was because I had to plan with precision, each sentence I type to avoid grammatical errors and to communicate my question well (and to ensure that my question does not get hit with a series of downvotes). ***So how does increasing the communication speed between my brain and the computer actually guaranty that I will type this question faster than I'm typing now*?**
3. **If such a thing is actually possible, can you explain (*in brief*) how will such a method work?**

Comment: Some related questions: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8604/is-there-a-report-of-a-successfully-eeg-based-brain-computer-interface-bci-usi ; https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/14132/11318 . In short, it is possible, yes.

Comment: I understand. So he was talking about communicating the images we see or imagine, and the sound we hear. So these forms of information will require a *lot of bytes* as we switch between numerous mental images or thoughts every second.  But **constructed solutions** like the sentences we write are *results of our brain's computation process*. But if such an interface exists, **we can communicate the process along with the result, and the information depicting the process is what takes more time and space.** Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure I agree that this is necessarily a duplicate as indicated by @mfloren.  There is little information on Neuralink's website on what they are trying to achieve

Comment: Regarding " actually guaranty that I will type this question faster than I'm typing now?" It's not about guaranteeing anything. But I think it would be impressive and useful if this kind of communication would work for any practical cases.